# How to catch a string using regex in python and replace it by desired string

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and I wrote the following code which suppose to catch a specific string and replace it with a specific string as well.
sid=\"1722407313768658\"

I used this regex: sid=(.+?)
but it catches irrelevant string as well
https://tmobile.demdex.net/dest5.html?d_n**sid=0#**

as well when I am running this regex on sid=\"1722407313768658\" (replacing it with 1900117189066752 , I am getting the following result which does not replace the string but add i: sid=\1900117189066752\ "1722407313768658\"

(instead of 1722407313768658 i want to have 1900117189066752 )

this is my python code:

```
 import re
                content = c.read()

                ################################################################

                # change sessionid in content
                replace_small_sid = str('sid=\\' + "\\"+str(sid) + "\\" + " ")
                content = re.sub("sid=(.+?)", replace_small_sid, content)
```

Comment: If you are searching for a _specific_ string, you don't need regex. Just use `str.replace`. Regex is designed for searching for _patterns_ ,i.e. is certain strings, which have a special structure, like "first two chars are digits, then 3 to 5 captal letters,..." or sth like that

Comment: I'd advise you to find an online regex tester, like this you might easily test how your regex is behaving.

Comment: See [how do i replace a query with a new value in urlparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221669/how-do-i-replace-a-query-with-a-new-value-in-urlparse)

Comment: @SpghttCd I don't know what will be the value after sid= it could be any number so I have to use regex.

Comment: Ok, but `.` stands for any character, not only numbers. Aren't you just serching for a string containing nothing but numbers?

Comment: What about 're.sub('sid=\"\d+\"', replace_small_sid, content)'

Comment: @SpghttCd - nope it does not work , I tried this:
replace_small_sid = str('sid=\\"' + str(sid) + "\\\"")

                re.sub('sid=\\\"(.+?)', replace_small_sid, content)
which produce the following result: 
sid=\"1900174890156032\"1722407313768658\" and did not change the string: 
1722407313768658 but added my replacement.

Comment: I used this regex: 'sid=\\\"(.+?)\\"' which caught me the number but it did not replace it by what i want :
 content = re.sub('sid=\\\"(.+?)\\"', replace_small_sid, content)
to this string: 1900117189066752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you wish to match string patterns in the form:

> sid=\"1722407313768658\"

With the aim of replacing the digits.

To achieve this we can use positive lookbehinds and lookaheads as described here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

> Lookahead and lookbehind, collectively called "lookaround", are zero-length assertions just like the start and end of line, and start and end of word anchors explained earlier in this tutorial. The difference is that lookaround actually matches characters, but then gives up the match, returning only the result: match or no match. That is why they are called "assertions". They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

In this case our lookbehind will match

> sid=\"

Our lookahead will match

> \"

Please see the example here: https://regex101.com/r/2pXcMI/2

Finally, we can use this to match and replace as follows:

```
import re
line = "sid=\"1722407313768658\" safklabsf ipashf oiasfoi asbg fasnk sid=\"65641\" asjobfaosb asbfaosb asf asfauv sid=\"651564165\"."
replace_with = '1900117189066752'
line = re.sub('(?<=sid=\\\")\d+(?=\\\")', replace_with, line)
line
```

This returns

> 'sid="1900117189066752" safklabsf ipashf oiasfoi asbg fasnk sid="1900117189066752" asjobfaosb asbfaosb asf asfauv sid="1900117189066752".'

Comment: It's a bit strange but when I try to replace the string it does not let me...
although by testing the regex I saw that it caught the number for some reason it did not change it to the desired string. very strange!

Comment: If you're able to copy the code you used here it shouldn't (hopefully) be hard to debug.

Comment: That's the problem I debugged my code my regex actually catch what it is suppose to catch but when I want to replace the strings it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Are you assigning re.sub(pattern, replacement, original_string) to an object? 

For example:

line = re.sub('(?<=sid=\\\")\d+(?=\\\")', replace_with, line)

Comment: Unless you can provide the exact code and similar data such that such that the error is reproducible, I'm not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to replace specific string, you can do it by:

```
content.replace("1722407313768658","1900117189066752")
```

Comment: My first thought, too, but OP already made clear that they in fact want the general substitution, i.e. it's really a regex case.

Comment: @Gautam Kumar - I want to be able to catch any string containing digits and replace it in another string containing digits.