# Replacing URL string with values from a CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, url, scripting

Hope you are doing well, i have a csv file where i have 4 columns:

```
id,       h,      w,     x,   y
ddd:1234  52      11     22   33
```

and from the following link i want to replace the same attributes from the link with the ones from the csv:

www.example.com/ImagingService/imagingService?id=ddd:0104:image&coords=ddd:0104:alto&w=244&x=12&h=321&y=12

How can i replace the id,h,w,x,y from the url with the ones from the CSV?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607870/how-to-change-values-of-url-query-in-python and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221669/how-do-i-replace-a-query-with-a-new-value-in-urlparse

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change values of url query in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607870/how-to-change-values-of-url-query-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Python `DictReader` to read each row of your CSV file as a dictionary. This can then be passed to `urlencode` which returns the correctly encoded URL to use. For example:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import csv

with open('parameters.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        url = f"https://www.example.com/ImagingService/imagingService?{urlencode(row)}"
        print(url)
```

So if you had a `parameters.csv` file which had the following:

```
id,h,w,x,y
ddd:1234,52,11,22,33
aaa:5678,62,44,55,66
```

You would get the following output:

```
https://www.example.com/ImagingService/imagingService?id=ddd%3A1234&h=52&w=11&x=22&y=33
https://www.example.com/ImagingService/imagingService?id=aaa%3A5678&h=62&w=44&x=55&y=66
```

In your example, there is a `coords` parameter, it is not quite clear how this is created. It could be added as another column in the CSV file or by adding a line before the url line as follows:

```
row['coords'] = row['id']   # or whatever format is needed
```

---

Note: If you intend using the `requests` library, the `urlencode()` is not required. For example:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com/ImagingService/imagingService", params=row)
```

---

You could write each URL to an output CSV file as follows (currently with just one column)

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import csv

with open('parameters.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['url'])    # write the header
    
    for row in csv_input:
        url = f"https://www.example.com/ImagingService/imagingService?{urlencode(row)}"
        print(url)
        csv_output.writerow([url])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution it's really helpful. How can i write the results in a csv file?

Comment: You can use a simple `csv.writer()`, I have updated the answer to show you how.